# Почему функция filemtime работает с задержкой?

Tags: php

Написал класс который отслеживает изменения в файлах, но почему-то перехват изменения происходит с задержкой в пару секунд.

```
<?php


namespace App;


class CheckChange
{
private $srcDir;
private $srcExt;
private $structureUnitMTimes = [];

public function __construct($config)
{
    $this->srcDir = $config['compile']['srcDir'] ? $config['compile']['srcDir'] : './';
    $this->srcExt = $config['compile']['srcExt'] ? $config['compile']['srcExt'] : 'bea';
}

public function start() {
    $this->loop();
}

private function makeStructure($srcDir) {
    $units = scandir($srcDir);
    $units = array_slice($units, 2);

    $structure = [];

    foreach ($units as $unit) {
        $unitPath = $srcDir . '/' . $unit;

        if (is_dir($unitPath)) {
            $structure = array_merge($structure, $this->makeStructure($unitPath));
        } elseif (pathinfo($unitPath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == $this->srcExt) {
            $structure[] = $srcDir . '/' . $unit;
        }
    }

    return $structure;
}

private function loop() {
    while (true) {
        $structure = $this->makeStructure($this->srcDir);

        foreach ($structure as $unit) {
            if (array_key_exists($unit, $this->structureUnitMTimes) == false) {
                $this->structureUnitMTimes[$unit] = filemtime($unit);
                $this->findNewOrChange($unit);
            } elseif ($this->structureUnitMTimes[$unit] < filemtime($unit)) {
                $this->structureUnitMTimes[$unit] = filemtime($unit);
                $this->findNewOrChange($unit);
            }
        }
    }
}

private function findNewOrChange($unit) {
    var_dump($unit . ' на компиляции...');
}
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.filemtime.php#refsect1-function.filemtime-notes

Comment: Добавил clearstatcache(true, $unit); Вроде работает, но все-равно медленно